# Speed up computing the $n$-th hexadecimal digits of $\pi$, by using BBP formula

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics

Let

$$S_j=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16^k(8k+j)}$$

Then

$(n+1)$-th hexadecimal digit of $\pi$ given by the fractional part of

$${\lbrace 4\lbrace 16^{n} S_1\rbrace-2\lbrace 16^{n} S_4\rbrace-\lbrace 16^{n} S_5\rbrace-\lbrace 16^{n} S_6\rbrace \rbrace}$$
 where $\lbrace \rbrace$  denote the fractional part.

```
S[j_] := Sum[1/(16^k (8 k + j)), {k, 0, Infinity}]

d[n_] := FractionalPart[4 16^n S[1] - 2 16^n S[4] -  16^n S[5] - 16^n S[6]]

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity}, BaseForm[N[d[35000], 10], 16]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {$21.235$, $0.3dd4d992_{16}$}

I want to speed up this calculation by using [following result](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/bbp-alg.pdf)

$$\lbrace 16^{n} S_j\rbrace=\bigg \lbrace \bigg \lbrace\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{16^{n-k} \mod {8k+j} }{8k+j} \bigg \rbrace+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{16^{n-k}}{8k+j}\bigg \rbrace$$

```
s[j_, n_] :=FractionalPart[Sum[PowerMod[16, n - k, (8 k + j)]/(8 k + j), {k, 0, n}]] + 
Sum[16^(n - k)/(8 k + j), {k, n + 1, Infinity}]

dd[d_] := FractionalPart[4s[1, d]-2s[4, d]-s[5, d]-s[6, d]]

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity},BaseForm[N[dd[35000], 10], 16]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {$92.1169$, $-0.a009044_{16}$}

but the result is  different than expected.

Comment: There are two mistakes in the code posted.

 1) `S[j]` does not reflect the given $S_j$ i.e., `k` should start from `0`, but it starts from 1.

 2) `d[n]` definition doesn't have `Fractional part` inside `Fractional part` as given. 

After applying these corrections, the result of both the approaches is same. However, w.r.t to timing, the first one performs better than the second one.

Comment: @AnjanKumar ok, there is only one mistake,($0$ instead $1$ ).  If you write `Fractional part` inside `d[n]`, you get wrong  [result](http://imgur.com/2gDM1Vs)

Comment: @vito the first formula isnt work correctly for me i checked feynman point and the formula give me wrong result...???